# Keep WPF UI responsive - Communication between classes

Tags: c#, wpf, events, action, eventhandler

In our WPF application, we have classes that need to "raise" a notification that something has happened, and other classes that operate as listeners to that notification and have to execute some code as a response upon getting that notification. This is the common pattern of Publish/Subscribe.

Now, I will show you how it is done in our project. I think we use a bad practice of that pattern, and this causes our UI to freeze and not be responsive as expected.

***The event args class:***

```
public class IsDisconnectedAction : EventArgs
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType() + " Key: ";
    }
    public ElementType ElementKey { get; set; }
    public static ActionTemplate<IsDisconnectedAction> MY_Action = new ActionTemplate<IsDisconnectedAction>();
}
```

***Raising the Notification***

```
IsDisconnectedAction.MY_Action.Raise(new IsDisconnectedAction() { ElementKey = _elementKey });
```

***The implementation of the Raise method***

```
public void Raise(T info)
{
    if (_event == null) return;

    InvokeIfNecessary.Invoke(() =>
    {
        _event (null, info);
    });

}
private event EventHandler<T> _event;
public event EventHandler<T> Event
{
    add
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _event += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _event -= value;
        }
    }
}
private readonly object _lock = new object();
```

***The Invoke method of InvokeIfNecessary***

```
public static void Invoke(Action action)
{
    if (Application.Current == null)
    {
        action();
        return;
    }
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        action();
    else
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Send);             
    }
}
```

**NOTE** this code is executed on the UI thread, and I think it's not the correct approach.

Then, the listener:

1. It can be a class in the UI that indeed need to update something in the UI:

   IsDisconnectedAction.MY_Action.Event += OnElementDisconnected;

   private void OnElementDisconnected(object sender, IsDisconnectedAction e)
   {
       if (e == null) return;
       _textBlock.Text = "Disconnected";
   }
2. It can be a class that listens to the events in the same manner but does NOT even need to update anything in the UI (Here I think that raising the event and listening to it, can all be done outside of the UI thread).

Can you please suggest what is the best practice to achieve what I want? 
Sometimes these events are raised so many times per second and all of that happens in the UI thread, and I think it might harm the responsiveness of the UI. Thank!

Comment: You explicitly always raise events on UI thread via `Dispatcher.Invoke` so what do you expect? Either don't do that (but then event handlers will run on the thread which raised event, which still might be UI thread), or explicitly run heavy event handlers on background thread.

Comment: You should have a look on the await/async pattern and force ActionTemplate to return a Task<>. so you will make sure that the long lasting operations won't be done in the GUI but only the response. Also have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx as it takes care of GUI dispatching

Comment: @Evk Is raising the event itself on the UI thread considered as a heavy operation or only the code executed in event handler? I mean, can I leave the code as it is (raising the event on the UI Dispatcher, and subscribing to it), and just change the code executed in the event handler (the method with the signiture : private void OnElementDisconnected(object sender, IsDisconnectedAction e)), so its code would run on a background thread and only parts that involve UI updates will be wrapped with Dispatcher?

Comment: Yes, only code that runs in event handler can be heavy, not dispatch to UI thread itself. So changing only event handler code to run on background thread (if that code is "heavy" and can block UI thread, so not on every event handler - just where necessary) is good enough.